# aggregate query without group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the Supplier-Project-Part database. I have written a code for the query: "Get project number and the average of supplied parts for that project".
I have done that using GROUP BY. I was wondering if I could do that without GROUP BY.

---

Database:

```
SUPPLIER(SNUMBER, SNAME, STATUS, CITY)
PROJECT(JNUMBER, JNAME, CITY)
PART(PNUMBER, PNAME, CITY, COLOR, WEIGHT)
SPJ(SNUMBER, PNUMBER, JNUMBER, QUANTITY)
```

---

EDIT 1: I edited the query. The query is: "Get project number and the average of **WEIGHT** of supplied parts for that project. **Each supplied part must count once.**"

Comment: When you come along any aggregate requirements like average, sum, count or something similar, `GROUP BY` is what you need to do. Other options are usually slow, complicated and unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to compute the aggregated values:

```
SELECT JNumber,
       (SELECT SUM(Quantity * Weight) / SUM(Quantitiy)
        FROM SPJ
        JOIN Part USING (PNumber)
        WHERE JNumber = Project.JNumber
       ) AS AvgParts
FROM Project
```

This is typically just as fast as a join with GROUP BY, but slightly more complex.

Comment: Actually, this method can be (but not always is) much faster than an explicit `group by`, although I prefer the explicit `group by`.

Comment: Thanks. This contains the idea I was looking for. However, I edited the query. I'm afraid I didn't provide the correct form of the query at first.